# To give Universal href link that should work in local and Deployed version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, href

Below is the `href` link where i want to redirect the user from one page to another

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Id).ClientTemplate("<a href=' /User/Edit/" + "#=Id#' class='k-grid-Edit' style='width: 26px; height: 26px;vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;' ><span style='margin: 4px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'  ></span></a>").Title("Action").Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
```

But the problem is it is redirecting to other page successfully in Local only and after deployed ths link is not working because that site is deployed inside another root directory.
Can someone help me to give solution which will work on both local as well as in Deployed version

Comment: how about parameters?

Comment: tried..but giving compile time error

Comment: `"<a href='@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person" , new {id = "Id"})' class='k-grid-Edit' style='width: 26px; height: 26px;vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;' ><span style='margin: 4px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'  ></span></a>"`

Comment: what is the exception. Are you getting it in view?

Comment: Is id a string? Please try new {id = 1} , I can see the link is generated correctly

Comment: id is long type

Comment: actually the problem is i need to bind Id here is dynamically..because this record will be visible in Grid. so i am trying to pass `Model.Id` but it is coming as 0

Comment: then it is another problem. Chekc Id is passed